# Is Quelling Blade's bonus damage stackable?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Is [Quelling Blade](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Quelling_Blade)'s bonus damage to creeps and neutrals stackable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do not stack.

There's also seem to be a bug in the sense if you have 2 Quelling Blade in your inventory and drop one the game removes the bonus as if you didn't have any.

More info [here](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=49198&page=2&p=303244&viewfull=1#post303244)